# problema con hide(), show() de jquery al cambiar la resolución de pantalla

Tags: html, jquery, css

La cuestión es que tengo un nav que desarrolle en la parte superior de la pantalla o pagina como quieran llamarle, todo esto con una resolución mayor a 600px de ancho, ahora cuando la resolución es menor se "esconde" el nav mediante un display:none y se visualiza una barra de menú con un display:block en la parte superior que al hacer click en dicha barra se ejecutan el " show() y el hide()" de jquery, permitiendo mostrar u ocultar el nav(reponsive), funciona todo correctamente excepto en una circunstancia especifica que paso a detallar.
Estar en el navegador desde el escritorio, minimizo el mismo(menos de 600px) por ende aparece la barra de menú, haciendo click aparece el nav (mediante show()), después vuelvo a clickear y se esconde(mediante hide()) pero si seguido a esto maximizo la pantalla ya no aparece el nav en la parte superior como debería al tener un ancho de mas de 600px, he probado un montón de ideas pero no logro que funcione..
Paso el codigo del html con el script jquery dentro y añado el css.

```css
/* ------------------------ ESTRUCTURA GENERAL-------------------------------- */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
 
}

.columna.side {
  width: 30%;
  background-color:#aaa;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.columna.medio {
  width: 69.67%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:#bbb;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pie-pagina {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
.header-arriba{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color:#2b2a2a ;
}
.header-abajo{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color:#686565 ;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* ------------------------BARRA DE NAVEGACION-------------------------------- */

.nav{

    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg,rgb(0, 159, 252), rgb(27, 149, 158));
    padding: 20px 25px;
}

.nav a{
  display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
    color:white;
  margin-left: 0%;
  border-right: solid 1px white;
  font-size:30px;
  text-align: center;
  }
.nav a:last-child{
  border-right: none; 
}
.nav a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(104, 198, 252);
}

.menu_bar{
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .columna.side, .columna.medio {
    width: 100%;
    }
  .nav a{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    }
  .nav{
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    line-height: 23px;
    padding: 0;
    position: sticky;
    top:50px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    }
  .menu_bar{
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg,rgb(0, 159, 252), rgb(27, 149, 158));
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    }
  
  .menu_btn{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 30px 11px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
  .menu_btn:hover{
    background-color: rgb(104, 198, 252);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>OBSERVATORIO</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum- 
    scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="estilos.css" TYPE="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var contador=0;
        $(".menu_bar").click(function(){
            if (contador== 0){
                $('.nav').show(600);
                contador= 1;
            }
            else{
                $('.nav').hide(600);
                 contador = 0;
            }       
         });
     });
    </script>
    <div class="header">
    <div class="header-arriba">
        ARRIBA
    </div>
    <div class="header-abajo">


    </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="menu_bar" id="menu_bar">
        <a class="menu_btn">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav" id="nav">
            <a href="#">Inicio</a>
            <a href="#">Trabajos</a>
            <a href="#">Proyectos</a>
            <a href="#">Servicios</a>
            <a href="#">Contactos</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="cuerpo">
    <div class="columna medio">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
     labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
     consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
     pariatur.
        Excepcional sint occasionecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
     anim id est laborum. 
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="columna side" >
      Columna
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pie-pagina">
    <p>Pie de pagina</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Por alguna razón no me permite cambiar la resolución en el snnipet como para poder ver el ejemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media(min-width: 600px) {
  .nav{
    display: block !Important;
  }
}
```

Añade esto a tu CSS. el problema es que usas el mismo nav en ambos casos, y cuando lo ocultas en Responsive, luego no hiciste ninguna condicion para mostrarlo si la pantalla superaba los 600px

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, eso me funcionó, ahora quisiera comentarte que en su momento use el mismo código pero sin el " !important " y por ende no sirvió, es mas nunca lo había visto hasta ahora pero ya lo investigue. Nuevamente Gracias. @Matias Heredia